# Отступ справа при уменьшении ширины экрана

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, responsive

На ширине - 1116px отступа еще нет(рис.1), но при уменьшении ширины дисплея начинает появляться отступ в правой части экрана и продолжает расти по мере сужения вьюпорта(рис.2). У body и html никаких отступов нет.

Чем это может быть вызвано и как решить эту проблему?

Ссылка на верстку: beast1.github.io /works/dev/src/index.html

Рис.1:
[image: рис.1]

Рис.2:
[image: рис.2]

Comment: 1) <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 2) html, body{overflow-x: hidden;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите:
Все из-за того что у Вас где-то блок который в средине обертки имеет большую ширину чем вьюпорт или там текст не помещается. Вам нужно все блоки проанализировать на ширину в инспекторе и найдете нужный

Answer (score 0):

1 способ
Чаще всего такая проблема возникает,когда margin или padding (по бокам) придают статический (px;em..) лучше всего работать с процентами. 
Проверь появляется ли Скролл при уменьшение ширины.. посмотри из за какого элемента этот скролл.. 
2 способ 
Придать родительскому классу
{overflow-x: hidden;}

Answer (score -1):

Если отступ никакой не нужен сделай для `body`:

```
width 100% margin 0 padding 0
```